# Upload image received via Flask to Firebase Storage

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, flask, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase storage.  The image is passed via HTTP Post.  The request is processed using Flask.  I can't seem to get the image to upload correctly.  When I specify the image's location I can successfully upload the image, ruling out the issue with Firebase or that code.  I have tried to get the file location, but unfortunately Flask has prevented this for safety(Probably a good thing).  Is there something I need to do to process the image before storing it?.

I am using Postman to send the POST request.

```
@message_api.route('/messenger/message/send/picture/individual', methods=['POST'])
def send_individual_picture():
    picture = request.files['picture']

    firebase.storage().put(picture)
```

Comment: `request.files['picture']` is going to be a wrapper class of type [`FileStorage`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) - what does `firebase.storage().put()` expect as an argument? A byte stream? A path?

Comment: It expects the file path location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `firebase.storage().put()` expects a file path, then you'll need to save the upload to a file first before you can store it.

Right now you have this:

```
@message_api.route('/messenger/message/send/picture/individual', methods=['POST'])
def send_individual_picture():
    picture = request.files['picture']

    firebase.storage().put(picture)
```

After this, `picture` is an instance of Werkzeug's [`Filestorage`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) class, which can be treated somewhat like a file descriptor. You can do stuff like `read()` from it.

Since your code is really treating the file as transient and you don't need it hanging around afterward, you can use a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) which creates a temporary file with a name. You can then delete the temporary file afterward.

```
import os
import tempfile

@message_api.route('/messenger/message/send/picture/individual', methods=['POST'])
def send_individual_picture():
    picture = request.files['picture']

    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    picture.save(temp.name)
    firebase.storage().put(temp.name)

    # Clean-up temp image
    os.remove(temp.name)
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to save the image and quickly delete it after uploading and it works perfectly!