# Upload PDF files directly via Flask to Firebase Storage using Pyrebase without storing them temporarily on the server

Tags: python, firebase, flask, pyrebase

This is what I have tried so far.

HTML

```html
    <form method="post" action="/submit-file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Select File</label>
        <input name="file" id="fileId" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit File">
    </form>
```

Flask

```py
@app.route("/submit-file/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file_to_storage():
  if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = 'insert_function_to_generate_unique_id_here()'
        file.save(filename)
        firebase.upload_file_to_storage(filename)
```

Pyrebase

```py
def upload_file_to_storage(file):
    storage.child().put(file)
```

I know that the put requires the file location locally(on the server).
How can I still achieve this so that users can upload the files to the folder storage directly without saving the file temporarily on the server?

Comment: I found this temporary solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163940/upload-image-received-via-flask-to-firebase-storage?rq=1

Comment: These links are also helpful: 

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save