# Flask website how to add uploaded file directly to firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-platform, file-upload

I have a flask web page where the user can upload files and on clicking the submit button, they get saved in a folder on my system(called UPLOAD_FOLDER in code).

My goal is to make it happen such that, on clicking the submit button, the chosen files get uploaded to my firebase inside a folder called `pos` instead of a local folder on my system.

Here's what my `app.py` currently looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

import urllib.request
import pyrebase
config={
 #config stuff
}

 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
UPLOAD_FOLDER = r"C:\Users\mihir\settls\PO\POs\fbpdfs"
firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage=firebase.storage()
 
app.secret_key = "Cairocoders-Ednalan"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf'])
 
def allowed_file(filename):
 return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
  
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
 return render_template("upload.html")
 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
 if request.method == 'POST':
        
  if 'files[]' not in request.files:
   flash('No file part')
   return redirect(request.url)
  files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
  for file in files:
   if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
  flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
  return redirect('/')
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's what I tried to change in the `upload_file()` function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
 if request.method == 'POST':
        
  if 'files[]' not in request.files:
   flash('No file part')
   return redirect(request.url)
  files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
  for file in files:
   if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    
    path_on_cloud="pos/"+filename
    path_local=filename
    storage.child(path_on_cloud).put(path_local)
  flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
  return redirect('/')
```

But it doesn't work and is giving me a "No such file or directory error"

Answer (score 1):

Firebase hosting does not have persistent storage by itself. It is common practice to store the file in Cloud Storage. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163940/upload-image-received-via-flask-to-firebase-storage), which saves the file as a temporary file before it is uploaded to Cloud Storage:

```
import os
import tempfile
import firebase

...

file = request.files['file']
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
file.save(temp.name)
firebase.storage().put(temp.name)

# Remove temp file
os.remove(temp.name)
```

Comment: But what if I were to deploy the website, where would the temporary file be stored then?

Comment: Temporary file storage is usually stored in memory or temporarily on disk.

Comment: So if someone else were to use the website ,  where they won't have any of the python/flask source files , they wouldn't have to download a temporary file or anything right?

Comment: The code is running in the backend, so clients are not aware of that.

Comment: What exactly is 'picture' in this? How exactly should I apply this in my case , as I would be working with a list of files and would not be knowing the file names?

Comment: It was just an example of a file. You have a list of files, so iterate over that list and follow the same principle